# Returning DIV contents with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While this seems simple at first glance, I'm having trouble getting what I want.  I have many DIVs on a page with the same class which I use to find their text contents:

```
var Name =  $(".class").text();
```

While this works, it returns all of the text from all DIVs on the page at once such as

```
Name1Name2Name3Name4Name5
```

I am calling this request from a jQuery onclick event that is inside one of these DIVs.  So my goal is to get the contents of the DIV that the onclick was fired from, not everything.  The end result would be if I press the onclick from Name 3 it would only get the contents for that DIV, thus giving me Name3 only.

The DIV does have a unique ID I can also check against but I can't figure out how to use that to my advantage.  The DIV structure looks like:

```
<div id="2242yrcwrmz5t1zyt03" class="class1" tabindex="-1">
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `$("#2242yrcwrmz5t1zyt03").text();`? Or does the id change?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the element you clicked by using $(this)

```
$(".class").click(function(){
   alert($(this).text());  
});
```

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck, Nope, it gives the text of the div which one he clicked.

Comment: Sorry, I glazed over your answer at first. You are correct because you are using `$(this)`.

Comment: Thank you for that but I'm not clicking on the DIV which I want to extract the text from.  I'm clicking on another DIV within this one and both are housed under one that has the `<div id="2242yrcwrmz5t1zyt03" class="class1" tabindex="-1">` look.  Sorry for the confusion, it's pretty hard to explain.

Comment: More of your html markup would help to better understand what you need. Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/fsj2ff6d/). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: it's more along the lines of http://jsfiddle.net/fsj2ff6d/2/ where under one container DIV, I have the DIV with the text I want to extract IF I press the corresponding DIV "button" where the onclick event fires off the search for the text.

Answer (score 2):

Your click event is bubbling up in the DOM hierarchy you need to stop that which could be done by using [event.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('.class1').click(function(event){
     alert($(this).text());
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So read the text from the current div with `this`

```
$(".class").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the `event.target` property to find the element that you actually clicked on.

Assuming your DIV that contains Name1, Name2, etc. has the id `outerElement`:

```
$("#outerElement").on("click", function(e) {
  var Name =  $(e.target).text();
});
```

More info here:
https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 0):

If you click an element inside the div, you should use

```
var name = $( this ).parent(".class").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery parent() method

```
$(this).parent().text()
```

heres jsfiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/c628Lwuq/